# Can the road go behind the Treasure Cards

Tags: saboteur-2, saboteur

Can the road go beyond the 9x5 card grid ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There is no limit on where you can build.

[image: Example]

Comment: There looks like a lot of saboteurs in that game!